# unable to download python package hosted at pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

**SOLVED**

forgot to run command

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

I have just uploaded a python module at pypi and it has been successfully updated in pypi database. However when i try to install it through pip it throws this message :

```
Downloading/unpacking textprocess
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement textprocess
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for textprocess
Storing complete log in /Users/mayankbhola/.pip/pip.log
```

package is hosted at : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textprocess/0.1

Comment: Verified the error. Ditto. No clue about it though.

Comment: Reporting it to pypi I think would be the best idea.

Comment: @psych0der please add the relevant log file details too.

Comment: it was really stupid on my part , just forgot to run command
''' python setup.py sdist upload '''

Comment: You should add the explanation/solution as an answer. And probably describe the problem shorter in the question. This could help people find your question / answer via search engines.